# Automatically create and update one to one relationships in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers, relational-database

I have a web shop (zen-cart)that has a very inefficient attribute schema. One option can be used for attributes for many products. (Instead of the other way around). I have tried to use views to make things easier, but creating new attributes is still very tedious. We have looked into changing the php-code, but it is too difficult. 
The solution is also multi-lingual, something I don't need.

The tables are the following:

```
tb_products:
prod_ID

tb_description:
prod_ID
lang_ID
product_name (T-shirt)

tb_attributes:
attr_ID
prod_ID
option_ID
values_ID

tb_options:
option_ID
language_ID
option_name (Size & Color)

tb_values:
value_ID
option_ID
language_ID
value_name (XS Red)
```

As a quick-fix, I would like to do the following:

1. Make the additional fields:

   ```
   tb_products:
   product_name
   option_name [optional - only if attributes are to be created]
   value_concatinator [optional]

   tb_attributes:
   value_name_1
   value_concatinator_1 [optional]
   value_name_2 [optional]
   value_concatinator_2 [optional]
   value_name_3 [optional]
   ```
2. Create a trigger, so that when I create a new row in tb_products, this will automatically create a new row in both tb_description and tb_options, with respectively product_name and option name taken from tb_products.
   Every time these fields are updated in tb_products, they must also be updated in tb_description and tb_options.
   Probably let the option_ID be the same as prod_ID
3. When creating a new row in tb_attributes, automatically:

   - Insert the option_ID from the parental product row.
   - Create a new row in tb_values. value_name is a concationation of the value names and value_concatinators in attributes

   CONCAT(value_name_1, ' ' , value_concatinator_1, ' ', value_name_2, ' ', value_concatinator_2, ' ', value_name_3) FROM tb_attributes

Every time these fields are updated in tb_attributes, they must be automatically updated in tb_values

So my main object is to actively only update the tables tb_products and tb_attributes, and let MySQL update the other tables every time a product or attribute is created or updated in the new fields mentioned above.

I am not sure if triggers are the answer, or if the columns themselves can be made to be automatically updated (and if the last solution will make some problems with how the columns are defined in the php-code.

For those of you who would like to make the values_names into an array: that is how it is supposed to be. But it doesn't work out with the quantities, so that customers can then actually add combinations that don't exist. People have spent 1000s of hours trying to fix it. To no avail. Now all I want is a solution that actually works backoffice-wise, and makes it easy for me to sort etc.

We use Filemaker and MagneticOne for normal backoffice activities, MySQL Workbench for changes to the database. I can read php, but the code is too complex for me to change (and even professionals make a lot of mess when trying to upgrade to newer versions, due to necessary customizations)

Comment: Glad you got that off your chest. So what is the problem?

Comment: how can I get automatic creation and updates of tables in one-to-one relationships? triggers? calculations of some sort?

Comment: That is a very detailed description. But what may really help you to improve your chances of getting your answer is to provide sample data for your desired schema in a tabular form.